# Exclude certain attributes with JPA @EntityGraph

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitygraph

I have a class called `Program` which contains a set of files (and other basic attributes), implemented as its own class `ProgramFile`, representing a multi-valued composite attribute of `Program` in the relational model. I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate.

The set of `ProgramFile` is implemented as follows in `Program`:

```
...
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name = "GPI_PROGRAMAS_FICHEROS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROGRAMA")
)
private Set<ProgramFile> files;
...
```

The code of `ProgramFile` is:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProgramFile {

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_FICHERO")
    private @NonNull String fileName;

    @Lob
    @JsonIgnore
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "FICHERO")
    private byte[] file;
}
```

`ProgramFile.file` are large PDF files and my goal is to serialize `Program` to JSON. In order to avoid the N+1 problem I'm using @EntityGraph to hint Hibernate at performing only one SQL query to retrieve all data:

```
@EntityGraph(
        type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD,
        attributePaths = {
                "files"
        }
)
List<Program> findAll(Specification<Program> spec);
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm only interested in `ProgramFile.fileName`, not in `ProgramFile.file`. Because the latter are large files the SQL query will be very slow and I don't want that attribute to be included in the JSON.

**Question: Is there any way to indicate Hibernate NOT to fetch `ProgramFile.file` or an alternative to achieve JSON serialization excluding it?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution:

1. Add Named graph to root entity (Program)

```
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = "program-without-filecontent",
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "files", subgraph = "program-files")
                },
                subgraphs = {
                        @NamedSubgraph(
                                name = "program-files",
                                attributeNodes = {
                                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "fileName")
                                }
                        )
                }
        )
})
@Entity
class Program { 
...
```

2. Use this Named graph in repository:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "program-without-filecontent", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Program> findAll(Specification<Program> spec);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nikolai. Unfortunately this throws an exception:

`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collection elements [files] is not of managed type`

Comment: Also my IDE is complaining about @NamedAttributeNode(value = "fileName"). It says: "Cannot resolve attribute node 'fileName'". As this EntityGraph is defined over Program and ProgramFile is defined in another .java document, maybe I cannot use one of its attributes because from Program I can't access them?